# Reading a mathametical notation

Tags: notation, set-partition, robotics, domain-theory

I am reading a paper on task allocation

```
Definition 3

Let j ∈ {1, …, Nt}. 

Then the utility of a task tj is defined as a function

 Uj:R+∪{∞}→R+ such that Uj(∞) = 0.
```

I am trying to understand how to read the infinity part and what does union with infinity mean

So its the function  Uj maps positive real number union with infinity to positive real number such as Uj with infinity domain equal 0

Is that correct way to read and how to interpret it?
The following is the reference article.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5261615/#pone.0170659.e020

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line);  $U_j$ is defined on elements of $\Bbb R$ or $\infty,$ and it maps $\infty$ to $0$

Comment: It's a bit of a headache to read this definition.  You'd have better luck if you use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for pretty typesetting. Welcome to math.se!

Comment: @JairTaylor I was actually looking for how to format it, thanks for putting the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properly typeset, as in the article, it is
$U_j$ is a function from $\Bbb R^+ \cup \{\infty\}$ to $\Bbb R^+$ such that $U_j(\infty)=0$

$\Bbb R^+$ is the set of positive real numbers.  The domain of the function is all the positive numbers plus infinity, which we sometimes call the extended positive reals.  It just adds one more point to the end of the line, which we call infinity and is greater than any other number.  Each $U_j$ is a function from this set to the positive reals.  Probably these functions are decreasing, but we are not told that at this point.  Then we specify that the value of the function is $0$ when the argument is $\infty$.  There is a glitch in the definition because the range is listed as $\Bbb R^+$, but the value at $\infty$ is $0$, which is not in $\Bbb R^+$.  Maybe $\Bbb R^+$ is intended to include $0$, or maybe the value of the function must be positive at all real inputs but is $0$ at infinity.

Sometimes using the extended reals lets you avoid talking about limits at infinity.  I haven't seen a case where the extended reals were necessary.  One could recast the argument to work in the standard reals by using limits.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. So essentially the function ranges from positive infinity downto 0? I do believe that the limit notation would have been more pertinent here.

Comment: We aren't told what the value of the function is at $0$ (if $0 \in \Bbb R+)$ or as it approaches $0$ so far.  We just know it has value $0$ at $\infty$.  The ones drawn are decreasing, but the definition doesn't say that.  They also started at some finite value, for what that is worth.

Comment: i see. thanks captain